# Is $y\approx0.206$ a solution to $e^{iy}\cdot\left(e^{iy}+e^{-iy}\right)=e^{iy}\cdot\left(8ye^{4y^2}\right)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, wolfram-alpha

Why, according to Wolfram Alpha, is $y\approx0.206$ a solution to [$e^{iy}+e^{-iy}=8ye^{4y^2}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7Biy%7D%2Be%5E%7B-iy%7D%3D8ye%5E%7B4y%5E2%7D) but not to [$e^{iy}\cdot\left(e^{iy}+e^{-iy}\right)=e^{iy}\cdot\left(8ye^{4y^2}\right)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(iy)*(e%5E%7Biy%7D%2Be%5E%7B-iy%7D)%3De%5E(iy)*(8ye%5E%7B4y%5E2%7D))?

Surely since I've multiplied both sides of the equation by a constant term, the solution should remain the same? Why doesn't it? Is there a mistake in my methods or in WA?

Thanks.

Comment: Wolfram does not show all solutions, just some of them. I guess it depends on internal algorithms of Wolfram, but all of them are valid.

Comment: @Sil I'd wondered that but rearranging the second equation and substituting the solution $0.206$ doesn't give $0$.

Comment: Well then i think there is mistake in that rearrangement, since that is valid solution (at least what i have checked in maple :)).

Comment: Added answer, as you wish

Comment: Revisiting this old question: there wasn't a mistake in my rearrangement (and in fact 0.206 is a root of the second equation). But Wolfram Alpha just doesn't list it as a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a mistake in your methods, since this root is indeed solution of both equations. Actually all solutions WA shows are valid for both of the equations. It is just confusing since WA shows only some roots and in this case they happen to be different for each equation, but still valid.